A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable Resource compilation failed
Helo,
I'm trying to compile my app in Android Studio, but when i press the play button I get the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file [pathtoapp]/app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5e857f8a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@14cc66ac.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@668c9068.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3562b0cc.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@406ee0c5.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@37601762.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@356dde36.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@15a9fc87.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@22f64e3f.). Check logs for more details.

I'm using some implementations, which I don't programmed. But in 2019 my app worked very good and then suddenly stopped working, since I tried to import in the year 2024 and upgraded to a newer gradle version.
What can I do? Where can I identify the error?
Finding ' and " symbols in values.xml, but there aren't such symbols. But in the module timezonepicker there are such symbols, don't know if it is significant.

Please share your build.gradle files

https://pastebin.com/EzZF1T2s

Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio. This will clear the cache and restart the IDE, which can help resolve issues related to cached data.

Does not work. I'm getting the same error.

I'm getting: Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file
